# Calling the method of React VideoJS component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having a react VideoJs component with markers on it in my react project. I have a function called jumpToSpecificMarker in it. I have another component havejumpToSpecificMarker which has names of these markers. All I want to do is call the jumpToSpecificMarker whenever I click listItem of this listview. Currently I am passing action a prop in my onTouchTap event to listItem. I want to pass this as well as fire the jumpToSpecificMarker function when it click listItem. I am using redux to handle the state whenever I click listItem.

Here is my code

```
export default class PlayerLogic extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            player : {}
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        var player = videojs(this.refs.video, this.props.options).ready(function () {
            self.player = this;
            self.player.on('play', self.handlePlay);
        });

        if (this.props.onPlayerInit) this.props.onPlayerInit(player);
         player.markers({
            markerStyle: {},
            markers: [
                {length: 8, startTime: 10, endTime: 15, time: 9.5, text: "Cigarette"},
                {length: 2, startTime: 20, endTime: 25, time: 16, text: "Cigarette"},
                {length: 15, startTime: 30, endTime: 38, time: 23.6, text: "Cigarette"},

            ]
        });

        this.setState({ player: player});
    }

    jumpToSpecificMarker(i) {
        this.state.player.markers.jumpToSpecificMarker(i);
    }

    render() {
        var props = blacklist(this.props, 'children', 'className', 'src', 'type', 'onPlay');
        props.className = cx(this.props.className, 'videojs', 'video-js vjs-default-skin', 'vjs-big-play-centered');


        assign(props, {
            ref: 'video',
            controls: true,
            width: "700", height: "450"
        });


        return (
            <div>
                <video {... props}>
                    <source src={this.props.src} type={this.props.type} id={this.props.id}/>
                </video>
            </div>)

    }
}
const mapStateToProps =(state) =>{
    return {
        tags: state.tagReducer
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlayerLogic);
```

I want to call the jumpToSpecificMarker function in above component from the another component which is

```
class TagListItemDetails extends Component {
    handleButtonClick() {
        browserHistory.push("TagList")
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <List id="parent-list-tags">
                        <ListItem primaryText="Kitchen" onTouchTap={() => this.props.tagSelected(0)}/>
                        <ListItem primaryText="Beach" onTouchTap={() => this.props.tagSelected(1)}/>
                        <ListItem primaryText="Marriage" onTouchTap={() => this.props.tagSelected(2)}/>
                        <ListItem primaryText="Garden" onTouchTap={() => this.props.tagSelected(3)}/>
                    </List>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps =(state) =>{
    return {
        tags: state.tagReducer
    };
};

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({tagSelected: tagSelected}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(TagListItemDetails);
```

Comment: At a high level the way to do this is to try to move your react state into a redux reducer. Try to initialise your state in a reducer, which seems to be the player object. Whenever you need to change the state, emit an action, which is processed by your reducer which can now update the player object.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using the `self.player` property that you defined in this block of code?

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    var player = videojs(this.refs.video, this.props.options).ready(function () {
       self.player = this;
       self.player.on('play', self.handlePlay);
   });
```

If this line of code is your mistake and you want to write `self.state.player = this` instead of `self.player`, please note that this does not update the state.

Comment: I am updating the state outside the componentDIdMount function. Look at my this,setState just after closing bracket of  componentDIdMount.

Comment: And my problem is not the state. My problem is calling one function from another component.